# What is the Dart Runtime?

Tags: dart

I studying a lot about Dart and Flutter and got some questions regarding the Dart Runtime and VM:

- What is the Dart Runtime?
- What is the difference between the Dart Runtime and the Dart VM?
- The dart code compiled to AOT can be considered the same process of Java compiling to Bytecode, since it needs a VM (or runtime) to run on a machine?

Answer (score 1):

Our video from I/O 2019 explains a lot of this – https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5DQRPRBiFI

Comment: Hey Kevin! Awesome presentation, thanks for sharing! But still the third question not answered: is the Dart AOT similar to what java bytecode is ?

Comment: Dart AOT compilation is unlike the Java Bytecode, in that it is native ARM code derived by tree-shaking the Dart source code and then transforming it to ARM.